# Klein & Rosenzweig family tree question

Tags: romania, transylvania

I am in search of family geneaology for my 2x great grandparents.  I knew my 2x great grandmother until I was 10 (I know crazy!), so I have some history on her side, but not my 2x great grandfather.  I have a few photos of him and a name, but unsure of spelling.  I am a member of Ancestry.com, but with the name Klein it's not easy to know for sure, and I'm unsure of how to correctly spell his name.  I have requested a birth certificate for my 1x great grandmother (their daughter b. 1908 in St. Louis), but do not have that yet.  I'm hoping he's named there.  He wasn't around long, so I'm unsure if they were even married.

Anna M Klein (b. 1887 d. 1973)  Family story born and/or raised in Transylvania.  Lived in St. Louis after immigrating around 1903.
siblings:  Johannes (John) 1871, Susanna 1884, Magdelana 1885, Margarete 1887 & Katherine 1894
Parents: Jacob Klein & Katherine Winkler
My 2x great grandfather?? Charles Rosenzweig (birth maybe around Anna's? 1887)  On the photos I have of him the name Helen is written on back, which we think was a later marriage.  Lived in California?

Is there a way to get records besides Ancestry.com or Family search to help me find more info on either of my 2x great grandparents, or their families?

Comment: Do you know the village or town in Transylvania? Do you know the religion[s]? Klein is a very common surname among Germans from all regions. Rosenzweig is not Transylvanian German, is usually (but not necessarily exclusively) Jewish. Ancestry and FamilySearch have church and civil records from Transylvania, but you'll have to pick the right haystack to find your needle.

Comment: bgwiehle - Formulate your two questions into statements, and then your comment becomes a very good answer you should post.

Comment: Anna M. Klein - on her passenger list her last residence was Szatamer.  She was a Christian, but I'm not sure if her or her family were Catholic, they did not have any Jewish traditions.

Comment: Charles Rosenzweig - I have a few documents I found on Ancestry.  Birth 12/15/1887 or 1888 in Bucharest Romania.  I don't even know if I have the correct person.